# How to use nth-child to display a 'brick' style view of multiple rows?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to build a 'brick' style view of multiple rows.

Assuming a 12 column grid displayed as below;

4col,8col

8col,4col

4col,8col

8col,4col

4col,8col

The repetition sequence for the 8column row is therefore 2,3,6,7,10,11

How to target the 8column rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way using `:nth-child()`

```css
div:nth-child(4n + 2), div:nth-child(4n + 3) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div><div>9</div><div>10</div><div>11</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The matching selector is

```
div:nth-child(4n+2), div:nth-child(4n+3) {...}
```

(if all these are DIVs and there are not other wrappers or similar)

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, html {
margin: 0;
}
div {
display: inline-block; 
border: 1px solid #ccc;
background: red;
}
.four {
width: 33.3%;
}
.eight {
width: 66.6%;
}
div:nth-child(4n+2), div:nth-child(4n+3) {
background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="four">4</div><div class="eight">8</div>
<div class="eight">8</div><div class="four">4</div>
<div class="four">4</div><div class="eight">8</div>
<div class="eight">8</div><div class="four">4</div>
<div class="four">4</div><div class="eight">8</div>
<div class="eight">8</div><div class="four">4</div>
<div class="four">4</div><div class="eight">8</div>
<div class="eight">8</div><div class="four">4</div>
```